Laravel Blade Template: CSS and JS Assets Disappear After Page Refresh
I am working on a personal project using the Laravel framework. I have placed my assets (CSS, JS, images) in the public directory. Here's how my project is structured:

I created an admin_master.blade.php file in the views/admin directory, which serves as my master layout for the admin dashboard.
In the layout file, I use the asset() helper function to link to CSS, JavaScript, and image files, like this:

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('backend/assets/images/favicon.ico') }}">


Then, I created another Blade file index.blade.php in the same views/admin directory, which extends admin_master:

@extends('admin.admin_master')


Inside the index file, I use the following section structure to extend the layout:

@section('admin')
    <!-- Some content here -->
@endsection


In the admin_master.blade.php file, I have defined a @yield('admin') section where the content from the index file is injected.

Everything works fine when I first load the page. All CSS and JavaScript files are loaded correctly. However, when I refresh the page, all my styles disappear, leaving the page unstyled. Interestingly, when I inspect the page and click on the links to the CSS files, I can still see the content of those files, but none of the styles are applied to the HTML elements.
Does anyone know what could be causing this issue and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

you seem to be doing things properly and nothing out of ordinary. can you somehow share your code for deeper inspection?

What counts as first-load for you? Usually, refreshing the page counts as first-load. If it isn't that, then how do you do first-load in that the styles are applied correctly?

Please share the code of redirection and your route and your ENV APP_URL, and check in Network tab of the navigator what URL of the Asset (CSS), maybe you have a extra slash (//) or something that break your URL

You can also try this code:
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url('backend/assets/images/favicon.ico') }}">

or,
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('backend/assets/images/favicon.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">

